# How to return blank when using text.befordelimiter but no delimiter found in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I am using Text.BeforeDelimiter in Power Query to grab all characters before `"---"`.
However, when there is no `---` found in some fields, I got all original text by default.
Is there anyway to get blank instead of the original text?

Most of the inputs are in this format
For example:

```
AAA.,
BBB.,
CCC.,
---
```

The field also allow to have `blank` input.
Sometimes, users did not put `---` .

Thank you.

I also tried to use Excel to get return BLANK but it did not work well

```
TEXTBEFORE(A1,"---",-1,,,"")
```

It is because I also use "group by" in Power Query so my field contains something like this:

```
AAA.,
BBB.,
CCC.,
---
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
CCC.,
DDD.,
---
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

This is why I try to work on PowerQuery to grab only texts before `---`

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, add column, custom column with

```
= try if Text.Contains([Column1],"---") then Text.BeforeDelimiter([Column1],"---") else null otherwise null
```

and replace [Column1] with the name of the column you are testing

[image]